# Non integer linear objective in or-tools CP-SAT

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

It seems that or-tools' CP-SAT solvers allows for non-integer coefficients in a linear objective expression. Am I correct, or is it just that the solver doesn't check for integrity and rounds the coefficients ?

Answer (score 3):

CP-SAT accepts floating point coefficients in the objective. It applies the necessary scaling to do all computation with integers, and report the unscaled objective.

It also displays in the log some statistics about the quality and precision of the scaling.